# KineticJS, MOVE shape and REMOVE Shape

Tags: kineticjs, removechild

I am trying to accomplish what is in theory simple..

I have a stage.. if the stage is empty a click on the stage places a layer with a circle object on the stage.. (I have a working code for this..)

If layer and object already exist on stage I would like to MOVE them to an x and y position..

I am unclear on whether it is better to destroy the object and create a new one or I can set X and Y and redraw ...

I tried both but I am not getting something right..

```
// I have a working code here that detects mouseX and mouseY position

// Detecting if object exists ( works fine )
    var theSpot = stage.find('.click_spot');

    if ( theSpot[0] === undefined ) {           
        //alert('Object not found, create a new one...');

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: mouseX,
          y: mouseY,
          radius: 30,
          fill: 'red',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 1,
          draggable: true,
          name:'click_spot'
        });

        layer.add(circle);
        stage.add(layer);

    } else {

// Move the object OR remove and draw a new one
// when I try to remove,, circle.remove(); does not remove it

        //alert('Object found, move it to new x, y location');

        circle.setX(mouseX); // I tried inserting values directly as well
        circle.setY(mouseY); // circle.setX(15) and circle.setX(15) but no joy...
        layer.draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will save resources and gain performance by reusing your existing circle rather than destroying and recreating a new circle.

**You have a scoping issue in your code.**

Since you're creating `var circle` inside your if statement, that circle variable is lost after the if completes.

You have several ways of "remembering" the circle.

The easiest way is simply declare `var circle` globally (outside and before the if statement).

You can also give the circle an id and later ask the layer to fetch the object with that id:

```
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
      id="myCircle",
      x: mouseX,
      y: mouseY,
      radius: 30,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      draggable: true,
      name:'click_spot'
    });

    // get the object by its id

    var myCircle = layer.get("#myCircle");

    // then you can use this reference to make your changes

    myCircle.setX(mouseX);
    myCircle.setY(mouseY);
    layer.draw();
```

Comment: Thank you markE.. I appreciate this.. your suggestion helped me solve this and some other issues.. I created a circle before manipulating it's position and instead of destroying and recreating I am essentially hiding and showing it when needed. I still do have some issues with actually removing unneeded objects but it is a separate issue and if I can't figure it out I will ask separately.